# fluentd logging nginx realtime

Tags: ruby, nginx, fluentd

I am working on a project where I'm looking at using fluentd. I need to parse the nginx access log in real time, probably using the in_tail. But a question arises when log rotation occurs.

Given this scenario, fluentd completes tail up until DAY1 23:59:00. Next scheduled run is in 2 minutes. So it will run again on DAY2 01:01:00. Meanwhile the nginx access log was rotated (file was most likely truncated).  Say there are 1000 log entries per minute. How would it be possible for fluentd to retrieve the last minute of DAY1 after the rotation. Can anyone give me some pointers?

Answer (score 1):

I think, fluentd will be read data from rotated file too if its will be updated after previus check

http://docs.fluentd.org/articles/in_tail
rotate_wait

in_tail actually does a bit more than tail -F itself. When rotating a file, some data may still need to be written to the old file as opposed to the new one.

in_tail takes care of this by keeping a reference to the old file (even after it has been rotated) for some time before transitioning completely to the new file. This helps prevent data designated for the old file from getting lost. By default, this time interval is 5 seconds.

The rotate_wait parameter accepts a single integer representing the number of seconds you want this time interval to be.

Answer (score 0):

Fluentd's in_tail isn't designed to catch up that amount of log rotation. I recommend you to use nginx Fluentd module instead.

- https://github.com/fluent/nginx-fluentd-module

Comment: Does nginx Fluentd module solve the problem of log rotation and disk space cleanup ??